# Logout users with devise gem rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

In admin section, I'm showing a list of currently logged in users. 
Now  admin can select one or more user/users and destroy their session(logout them).
I'm not able to figure where to start from,please help me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `sign_out` method in the controller action by passing in the user object:

```
# Make sure only admins can do this
def sign_out_user
    @user = User.find(params[:id])    
    sign_out @user  
end
```

More info here:

http://rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/TestHelpers%3asign_out

Comment: Is it necessary to use user controller or any controller will do?

Comment: I would create a specific action for admin users to use. I'll update my answer.

Comment: This would allow you to logout a specific user

Comment: Its logging out the admin instead of the user

Comment: Are you setting the @user variable to the selected user or the admin user?

Comment: I'm giving user object to sign_out I also tried abort @user.to_yaml and it was user data but its logging out the admin.

Answer (score 1):

Considering **users** is the collection of your required users,

```
for user in users
  sign_out user
end
```

It should solve your issue.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Its logging out the admin instead of the user.

Comment: Did you verify the 'users' collection? it could be, admin objects sent in 'users' collection.

Comment: I'm giving user object to sign_out I also tried abort @user.to_yaml and it was user data but its logging out the admin

Comment: See my answer for more details, but passing a user to sign_out will just logout everyone in the :user scope, as if you'd called `sign_out(:user)`.

Answer (score 1):

The `sign_out` method provided by Devise won't help. I know the documentation says that it will logout the "resource" you requested, but if you dig into the gems themselves (devise and warden) you'll find that when you give it an object, like a user, it merely figures out what scope (ie, :user) that object belongs to, and it logs out that entire scope.

A scope in Devise is a namespace for logins. You might have a Customer model that requires logins, but also a Vendor model that also requires logins, and you'd use different scopes for those. Most applications only use a single scope, tied to the User model.

You're probably using `:cookie_store` for your session storage, which is the Rails default. In this case, it isn't possible to log out any single user except yourself. Devise stores your login info in the session, which is stored in a cookie, and not in your database. Their browser has the credentials, so you can't directly remove that.